# setAlias("test") not working

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.18, alias

In QGIS 2.18.3, I want to set the alias for the fields.

```
layer.dataProvider().fields().field(0).setAlias("test")
```

That line returns no error but nothing is done.

I tried `layer.updateFields()`, but no alias set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use instead `QgsVectorLayer.addAttributeAlias`:

```
layer.addAttributeAlias( 0, "test" ) # 0 is the field index
```

As pointed out by @ndawson in the comments, using `layer.dataProvider().fields()` (or even `layer.fields()`) you get a copy of the layer fields. So, when you use `setAlias()` on them, you'll be affecting only that copy, without modifying the layer fields.

---

BONUS:

In QGIS v3, you can use `QgsVectorLayer.setFieldAlias`, see the [docs](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ab1b5f043f70d2d7e6279fac4545a0214).

Comment: It's actually not a bug - QgsVectorDataProvider.fields() just returns a copy of the fields, and can't be used to edit them (see https://qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html#a912e91f13ebe5f20bc82dcb0f96aef7b). As you've correctly noted this needs to be done through QgsVectorLayer.addAttributeAlias.

Comment: I also tested setAlias() directly from layer fields (avoiding the dataProvider method), i.e., layer.fields().field(0).setAlias("test"), which didn't work. Is that still expected behavior? If so, setAlias() documentation might warn about it or even suggest to use addAttributeAlias.

Comment: QgsVectorLayer.fields() also just returns a copy. Agreed that this documentation could be improved!

Comment: Tanks for your useful explanations